# Display 3d building using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, 3d

Is there any way to display a 3d building model as a layer under OpenLayers ? i have the building models drawn using Google sketchup , is that useful ?

Answer (score 1):

I think not, but OpenLayers accepts reading KML files. Try to export your sketch to KML and see how it is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Javascript library called [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org/showcase/3d/) that enables some 3D mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers doesn't support 3D. You can do it with other library like [ReadyMap](http://readymap.com/)